# multiply solution of linear congruence equation

Tags: congruences

let us consider the following theorem
[image]

i am surprised about this  theorem because if  we take for instance following equation
[image]

and if we divide both side by 2, we will get

[image]

one solution is 3 and another solution is  7, but there  another solution  11, because  $2*11=22$, $22-6=16$  and  definitely $8$ divides  $16$,  there is another solution  $19=3+16$  because $2*19=38$ $38-6=32$ and again  $32$ can be divided by  $8$,  then why is there exactly $d$ solution?in our case $d=2$

Answer (score 1):

The point is that 11=3 mod 8 as $11=8 \cdot 1 + 3$.
In general when you find a solution $x$ in a mod $ n $ you can find infinite solution in the form $ x+tn $ with $ t \in N$

Comment: yes but  exactly that is what i am asking, theorem says about finite solution, but there is  infinite solution

Comment: The point is that they belong to the same modulo class and hence you can consider 11=3. You have finite solution in the sense that they are exactly the same thing.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more to clarify  situation?

Comment: Of course, I'll try. 
Congruence is related to a clear equivalence relation: we say that $ a \equiv b $ $mod$ $n$ if and only if $ n | a-b$
In this enviroment we can define rest class and say that all the numbers that leaves the same rest in the Euclidean division are actually 'equal' to represent a class we only need a member of a class and we usually take the only number smaller of $n$ that belongs to such class.

Comment: that one i know, just i would like to  clarify  why  theorem says that there exactly  d solution mod n

Comment: i got point now